# How to properly use composer packages in wordpress?

Tags: composer

I need to implement in a wordpress instance a feature that allows me to search for the most recent file with extension .xlsx in the wp-content/upload directory, once the file has been identified, it should be interpreted and finally insert the excel data in the wp_posts and wp_postmeta tables Following a certain logic.

The packages of interest are

- symfony/finder
- phpoffice/phpspreadsheet

What is the correct way to integrate and use packages within wordpress?

I am new to worpress and I do not know how in the structure and philosophy of wordpress to do this. Thanks for the time.

Comment: You would just need to include your dependencies in your theme/plugin. WordPress itself doesn't have its own way of managing dependencies/composer packages.

Comment: thanks for answering. should I then reference the packages in the `vendor` directory from the functions.php file of the theme, for example, or from a plugin?

Comment: Yeah, you would just include the composer autoload.php file from the vendor directory in your functions.php or main plugin file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using composer for dependency management in plugindevelopment](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/127263/using-composer-for-dependency-management-in-plugindevelopment)